# get an "Expected 0 type arguments, but got 1.ts(2558)" when using useContext in a typescript environment

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

The code below gives the error mentioned in the title on `useContext<IDBDatabaseContext>`:

```js
interface IDBDatabaseContext {
  db: IDBDatabase | null
}

const DBcontext = createContext<IDBDatabaseContext>({db: null})
```

I've been looking for information on other sites, but I haven't been able to find a solution.

version:
typescript ^5.0.4
react ^18.2.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`useContext` does not take a generic, it can infer the type from your `DBcontext` when you pass it as the function argument.

```
const ctx = useContext(DBcontext);
// ctx is of type IDBDatabaseContext
```